# Spring Websocket Reply To User Message Flow

Tags: spring-websocket

I am trying to send a private message between users using spring-websocket.

I found the following:

https://github.com/rstoyanchev/springx2013-websocket/blob/master/spring-messaging/slides.md

which includes:

**Send Reply To User**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  // Message sent to "/user/{username}/queue/greetings"

  @MessageMapping("/greetings")
  @SendToUser
  public String greet(String greeting) {
      return "[" + getTimestamp() + "]: " + greeting;
  }

}
```

The above seems to imply that a message sent to "/user/{username}/queue/greetings" will invoke the greet method before sending the return value on to the specified user.

When I send a message to this destination, it gets sent to the directly to the user without being processed by the greet controller method.

Do I understand the expected flow correctly?  If I don't, what do I need to do to be able to process the message using a controller method before it's sent to a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@SendToUser` annotation defines that the return value of the method should be send to a user destination prefixed with `/user/{username}` where the user name is extracted from the headers of the input message being handled (current user).

In Spring 4.2 you can use placeholders in `@SendTo` (only destination variable placeholders, see [SPR-12170](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12170)), if you pass the username as a destination variable you could do something like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/greetings/{u}")
@SendTo("/user/{u}/queue/greetings")
public String greet(String greeting) {
    return "[" + getTimestamp() + "]: " + greeting;
}
```

This approach uses the `SimpMessagingTemplate` internally, so if you are using a version previous to 4.2, there's nothing wrong in using the `SimpMessagingTemplate` for dynamic destinations:

```
@MessageMapping("/greetings/{username}")
public void greet(@Payload String greeting, @DestinationVariable("username") String username) {
  String message =  "[" + getTimestamp() + "]: " + greeting;
  simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + username + "/queue/greetings", message);
}
```

Comment: Check out this presentation to know more about the workflow: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/spring-4-websockets

Comment: Thanks @Sergi Almar!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I think the new 4.2 feature is much more intuitive.  BTW, your demo (https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat) in addition to your presentation are excellent resources for learning spring websockets

Comment: Good to hear that, the sample app will be updated with all the upcoming features

Comment: @SergiAlmar how **subscribe** for to reply to user from methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` and also `@MessageMapping` ? see here [How to subscribe using Sping Websocket integration on specific userName(userId) + get notifications from method anotated with @RequestMapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47628608/3425489)

Answer (score 0):

Everything I can find points in the direction of the following pattern found in https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat :

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.private.{username}")
public void filterPrivateMessage(@Payload ChatMessage message, @DestinationVariable("username") String username, Principal principal) {

    checkProfanityAndSanitize(message); 
    message.setUsername(principal.getName());
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + username + "/queue/chat.message", message);

}
```

Applied to my scenario would become:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  // Message sent to "/app/greetings/{username}"

  @MessageMapping("/greetings/{username}")
  public void greet(String greeting) {
      String message =  "[" + getTimestamp() + "]: " + greeting;
      simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + username + "/queue/greetings", message);
  }

}
```