# Spring Boot 4.3.5 WebSocket Chat with jwt authorization. No destination in GenericMessage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ionic3, spring-websocket

I'm trying to implement a 1-1 chat for a mobile app(ionic 3) with a spring boot back-end. Seems like run into some config problems.

Can't send message probably because the target channel wasn't created

**Back-End:**

**ChatController:**

```
@RestController
public class ChatController {
    @Autowired
    private PrivateChatService privateChatService;

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ChatController.class.getName());


    @RequestMapping(value = "/chat/messages/{item_id}/chat_with/{buyer_login}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExistingChatMessages(@PathVariable("item_id") String itemId, @PathVariable("buyer_login") String buyerLogin) {
        List<ChatMessage> messages = privateChatService.getExistingChatMessages(itemId, buyerLogin);

        logger.info("Here get messages");
        return JSONResponseHelper.createResponse(messages, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @MessageMapping("/chat/{item_id}/send")
    @SendTo("/topic/chat/{item_id}/chat_with/{buyer_login}")
    public ChatMessage send(@Payload ChatMessage message,
                            @DestinationVariable("item_id") String item_id) throws Exception {
//        logger.info(principal.getName());
        logger.info(message.toString());
        logger.info(item_id);
        privateChatService.submitMessage(message);
        return message;
    }

}
```

**WebSocketConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private PrivateChatService privateChatService;

    private static final String MESSAGE_PREFIX = "/topic";
    private static final String END_POINT = "/chat";
    private static final String APPLICATION_DESTINATION_PREFIX = "/live";


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        if (registry != null) {
            registry.addEndpoint(END_POINT).setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        if (registry != null) {
            registry.enableSimpleBroker(MESSAGE_PREFIX);
            registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(APPLICATION_DESTINATION_PREFIX);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                    String authToken = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authentication");
                    String jwt = JwtUtils.resolveToken(authToken);
                    if (jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                        Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
                        accessor.setUser(authentication);
                        String itemId = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("item_id");
                        accessor.setDestination("/topic" + privateChatService.getChannelId(itemId, authentication.getName()));
                        logger.info(accessor.getDestination()); //ex: /topic/chat/3434/chat_with/user3797474342423
                    }
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**WebSocketSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Mobile client, ng2-stomp-service:**

```
 private _initWebsock(auth_token:string, item_id: number) {
    let headers: Object = {
      Authentication: `Bearer ${auth_token}`,
      item_id: item_id
    };

    this.stomp.configure({
      host :this.websocketApi + 'chat',
      headers: headers,
      queue:{'init':false}
    });

    console.log("Connecting stomp socket...");

    //start connection
    this.stomp.startConnect().then(() => {
      this.stomp.done('init');
      console.log('connected');

      //subscribe
      this.subscription = this.stomp.subscribe(`/chat/${item_id}/`, this.socketListener);
    });
  }
  public socketListener = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  };

  send(msg: ChatMessage, item_id: number){
    //send data

    console.log(msg);
    this.stomp.send(`/live/chat/${item_id}/send`, {}, JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
```

***Problem 1(probably):***

In the browser console it shows that a client subscribes to `/chat/item_id` instead of `/topic/chat/3434/chat_with/user3797474342423` => seems like `configureClientInboundChannel` doesn't work?

***Problem 2:***

When trying to execute `this.stomp.send(`/live/chat/${item_id}/send`, {}, JSON.stringify(msg));`, getting 
`o.s.m.s.b.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry    : No destination in GenericMessage [payload=byte[2], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE....` Error.

Comment: Hello, the https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html mention how to redirect messages to specific users, it is not clear but you can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464230/spring-websocket-reply-to-user-message-flow

Comment: Could you share the STOMP output in you console when sending the message and the complete error?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962402/8336511

This is how I solved this problem:

> When user authenticates with Spring Security, WebSocket module creates
>   unique channel for that user based on his Principal. Example
>   "/user/queue/position-updates" is translated to
>   "/queue/position-updates-user123"
>
> So on the client side all I had to do, was subscribe to
>   /user/queue/requests
>
> And on the server side, send messages to
>   /user/{username}/queue/requests with
>   convertAndSendToUser(request.getFromUser(), "/queue/requests",
>   request) and Spring handles the rest.

Comment: I suppose that if the channel was created, i this should work in the controller annotation? `@SendTo("/topic/chat/{item_id}/chat_with/{buyer_login}")` but instead i'm getting `No destination in GenericMessage` as described in topic